# Activiti usage of custom process variables

Tags: activiti

I have a process defined using activiti that has a start timer event. This start timer event gets its start date from a process variable that will be provided on initiation of the process.

**My question is how should I specify the reference to the process variable from within the xml process definition of an activi process?**

This is what I have tried:

```
<startEvent id="start_timer_event" activiti:initiator="initiator">
    <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDate>${initDate}</timeDate>
    </timerEventDefinition>
</startEvent>
```

The ${initDate} will be provided on initiation of the process instance, but when I try to let the activit engine validate the workflow using the above mentioned syntax it gives the following exception:

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in
>   expression: ${initDate}

sources of help I have inquired http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#apiExpressions

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a timer start event that references a process variable as the process instance doesn't exist yet.
You mention you have started the process, so perhaps you mean to be using an intermediate timer event (i.e. inline timer) that releases the token at the designated time.

Drop your process diagram into the thread to provide more context of what you are trying to achieve.